# ¿Qué función o método me permite comparar el valor obtenido en un prompt con un array?

Tags: javascript

El caso es que tengo un array con ciertos valores y que por medio de un prompt debo determinar si el valor que ha sido ingresado es igual o distinto. Qué funciones de los arrays me permiten comparar lo que se ingresó en un prompt contra un array?

Comment: La pregunta es demasiado amplia. Ayudaría que indicaras un ejemplos de datos de entrada y los resultados esperados. Por otro lado, la pregunta es de baja calidad ya que no se indica los buscado/investigado sobre el tema.

Answer (score 1):

Has algo así haciendo uso de la función `indexOf` del array:

```
var frutas = ["Banana", "Naranja", "Manzana", "Mango"];
var a = frutas.indexOf("Manzana");
```

El resultado será 2.

Y como @rnd menciona, si no lo encuentra en el array, este devuelve -1.

Comment: Falto mencionar el otro caso de la pregunta: Si el elemento no esta en el array, `indexOf` retorna -1

Comment: `var array1 = ["Maria","Marcos","Pedro", "Luis"];

            var pregunta = prompt("Verifica si tu nombre está en el array");
            if (pregunta == array1.indexOf(pregunta)) {
                alert("Nombre encontrado");
            }else{
                alert("Nombre no encontrado");
            }`

Comment: Cabe destacar que he intenado hacer eso con indexOf y nada. Ya que primero, el prompt devuelve un valor de tipo string y "pude" solucionar volviendo el array en string pero no me parace ideal tampoco. Entonces el indexOf debe de ver si en el array está un valor que sea igual al almacenado en el prompt y decir "Valor encontrado".

Comment: Considero que debería señalarse que esta es una respuesta parcial dado que la pregunta es demasiado amplia.  De todas formas voté positivo porque se incluye un ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo completo, usando `indexOf`.

```js
var arreglo = ["hola", "mundo", "que", "tal", "?"];

// verifica si la palabra solicitada esta presente o no en el arreglo
if (arreglo.indexOf(prompt("Di una palabra")) === -1) {
  alert("perdiste, no haz acertado ninguna palabra!")  
} else {
  alert("excelente, pero no se vale espiar el codigo fuente! :/")  
}
```

Comment: Excelente! Estaba cerca, sólo que no estaba comparando con -1 si no está.

Comment: Y que pasa si el array es multidimensional? Cómo puedo acceder a estos sin necesidad tener que evaluar cada uno por sepadado en un condicional?

Comment: @MarcAnt hay varias formas, como aplanar el array primero. La eleccion, tal vez dependa deque cosa haras despues, edita la pregunta y muestranos un ejempo de la estructura que estas pensando y edito mi respuesta. Salu2!!!

Comment: Considero que debería señalarse que esta es una respuesta parcial dado que la pregunta es demasiado amplia.  De todas formas voté positivo porque se incluye un ejemplo sencillo pero completo.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, deberías recorrer el array e ir comparando cada posición con lo obtenido en el prompt(), recuerda que un prompt devuelve información de tipo String.

La comparación sería algo así:

```
var string="loquesea";
    if(array[0]===string)...
```

Si no tienes la función `localeCompare(string);`

La usarías así:

```
var str1 = "ab";
var str2 = "cd";
var n = str1.localeCompare(str2);
```

El método `localeCompare ()` devuelve un número que indica si la cadena viene antes, después o es igual que el CompareString en orden de clasificación.

Te dejo más información aquí:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

Answer (score -1):

Los [Operadores Lógicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) tanto en PHP como en cualquier otro lenguaje son la forma comparar un valor contra otro.

En tu caso particular, tienes que comparar una variable obtenida de algun lado contra la variable que tengas dentro de un array. Normalmente se hace un loop al array para comparar ambos valores y rompes el loop cuando la encuentres.

Comment: La pregunta no es sobre PHP